# How to convert a long long to a binary character string?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

How can I convert a `long long` to an array of `char`'s that match up in the binary values? I'm working on a program where a binary string is sent over a network to control a lighting system. The way I have it set up now is I have a function that receives an `std::string`, then sends that to the clients. I would really like to keep this architecture (`std::string`s are easy to pass back and forth)?

Edit:
I'm looking for a binary serialization of a `long long` type as an array of bytes.

Comment: Perhaps via `std::bitset`? Or are you looking for a binary serialization of a `long long`?

Comment: @Columbo I'm looking for the binary serialization.

Comment: reinterpret_cast then?

Comment: Do you want 8 or 64 chars? If 8, be careful about processing the NUL-char. As in this case it does not signify the end of the string. E.g. concatenating such values and applying `strlen()` won't work.

Comment: Be also careful with undefined behavior and strict aliasing: unions for type pruning only legally work in C. Using `reinterpret_cast` for this also violates the rules and can sometimes lead to hard-to-find bugs. `bit_cast` (since C++20) is the correct cast and `memcpy` of the 8 bytes (often optimized by the compiler to register operations!) are the official ways.

Comment: Okay, `reinterpret_cast` to `char`, `unsigned char` and `byte` is allowed; but not back again in the other direction (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast#Type_aliasing)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using raw char array, you could simply go for:

```
char c[sizeof (long long)];
memcpy(c, &longlongValue, sizeof (long long));
```

edit:

or even:

```
char c[sizeof (long long)];
*(long long*)c = longlongValue;
```

which will probably be faster than a call to memcpy.

I agree this is not pretty c++, or c for that matter.

Comment: `long long` is a type, so it must be put inside brackets like this `sizeof(long long)`. Only with a variable you can omit the parentheses

Answer (score 1):

One thing you might consider is that the client and server on the network may have different [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

> The Internet Protocol defines big-endian as the standard network byte
>   order used for all numeric values in the packet headers and by many
>   higher level protocols and file formats that are designed for use over
>   IP. The Berkeley sockets API defines a set of functions to convert
>   16-bit and 32-bit integers to and from network byte order: the htons
>   (host-to-network-short) and htonl (host-to-network-long) functions
>   convert 16-bit and 32-bit values respectively from machine (host) to
>   network order; the ntohs and ntohl functions convert from network to
>   host order. These functions may be a no-op on a big-endian system.

[network byte order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Endianness_in_networking), that is, big-endian.  There is no standard library call to convert `long long` to and from network-byte-order.  Following are some templates that can be used to serialize and deserialize any integral type to and from a `std::string` in network-byte-order.  Live demo [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6c95717f6579226c).

To serialize

```
template< typename T >
string serialize( T val ) {
    string str( sizeof(T), 0 );
    for(size_t i=0; i<sizeof(T); ++i, val >>= 8)
        str[sizeof(T)-i-1] = char(val);
    return str;
}
```

To deserialize

```
template< typename T >
T deserialize( const string & data ) {
    T val = 0;
    for(unsigned char u : data) val = (val << 8) | u;
    return val;
}
```

And use it like this

```
long long val = 201501210654;
std::string str = serialize(val);
assert( val == deserialize<long long>( str ) );
```